# Cортировка List<String[][]>

Tags: java, массивы, строки, list, коллекции

Нужно написать функцию `void sort(List<String[]> rows, int columnIndex)`.  Где
`rows` список записей таблицы (например, результат sql select), которые нужно отсортировать по указанной колонке.

`columnIndex` - индекс колонки, по которой нужно провести сортировку. Я правильно  понимаю, что нужно сделать с помощью интерфейса `Comparator`? Если нет, то в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: @iksuy , когда вставляю твой комментарий в той теме и вызываю метод, появляются ошибки :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Task1Impl$1.compare(Task1Impl.java:15)
 at Task1Impl$1.compare(Task1Impl.java:12)
 at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
 at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
 at Task1Impl.sort(Task1Impl.java:12)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:21)

Comment: @iksuy, извиняюсь , моя вина . Пытался два разных типа сравнить

Comment: ну, вероятно значение `columnIndex` которое вы передаете больше, чем размер массива